# Do Rails or Heroku strip whitespace from HTML?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3 app, deployed to Heroku. I have a field for which preserving whitespace is important. The whitespace is always rendered fine on my local environment. When I inspect in the Chrome debugger tools, I see:

```
<div class="body-whitespace">dsfsdfdsf  dsfdsfdsfds
dsdsfdsf                     gdfgfdgdf



g gdg                    dgdgfds</div>
```

But on Heroku, it renders without the whitespace, and looks like this in the debugger tools:

```
<div class="body-whitespace">dsfsdfdsf dsfdsfdsfds dsdsfdsf gdfgfdgdf g gdg dgdgfds</div>
```

*Note* For some reason, when I do a forced refresh of the page (ctr shift R), the field is rendered correctly with whitespace.

I have a css rule setting the `white-space` property of `body-whitespace` to `pre-wrap` and, as far as I can tell, this is being applied correctly both locally and on Heroku.

I've checked the DB and the whitespace is definitely being preserved there.

Any ideas on why the whitespace is not being rendered in this div on my staging and production environments on Heroku?

**Edit**

I'm using ERB for templating. This is what the relevant bit from the `.html.erb` looks like:

```
<div class="body-whitespace"><%= model.body %></div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS for good measure:

```
.body-whitespace{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.body-whitespace{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Can you use `<pre>` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ExplosionPills. I need words to wrap normally over lines, which `<pre>` doesn't seem to do. I'm also using twitter boostrap which means I'll have to override a bunch of CSS rules.

Comment: This is likely an artifact of the HTML templating system you're using.  Are you using ERB or HAML?  Please post your template source code.

Comment: @Winfield I've given this a go using HAML instead of ERB. It still works fine locally, but strips the whitespace on Heroku. (I'm using HAML's `~` syntax to set the whitespace preservation.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an artifact of Chrome's view source tools.  Try using curl or wget on the command line to save the raw output of this page locally from heroku.  I bet it will have the whitespace correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Winfield. It's not a problem in the Chrome tools - the browser is not rendering the whitespace on the page (in Chrome and in other browsers). I was just providing the output of Chrome's 'inspect element' as extra debugging information.